# Dragging mouse can trigger WM_KEYDOWN message on qt QMainWindow

Tags: windows, qt, message

When I drag mouse(not in title bar) in QMainWindow, I can receive WM_KEYDOWN message in winEvent virtual function. I can also receive the WM_KEYDOWN message in spy, in which I can see VK_CONTROL AND "C" are pressed down.

When I double click a QMainWindow(not in title bar), same thing can happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the name WM_KEYDOWN is also triggered for mouse clicks. The WM_KEYDOWN's wParam is [described in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) as:

> The virtual-key code of the nonsystem key. See Virtual-Key Codes.

And if you look at [the documentation for virtual-key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), codes 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x05, and 0x06 all correspond with mouse clicks. Since dragging involves holding a mouse button down, this would be the expected behavior.

Comment: thanks. But 1) The ascii code 0x03(ctrl + c) doesn't map to any mouse clicks. 2) You cannot receive such a message when you drag a windows window instead of Qt window.